# Python: call "try-except" around just some parts of an "if-else" block?

Tags: python, exception

There are various similar question to this, but none quite seem to address my scenario. I find myself wanting to write some code similar to this:

```
try:
    if a:
        do_thing_a()
    elif b:
        do_thing_b()
    else:
        raise ValueError('thing not recognised!')
except ValueError as e:
    handle_error()
```

Except the problem is that I don't actually want to catch the `ValueError('thing not recognised!')` error here. I want it to propagate up. But I *do* want to catch `ValueError`s that might arise from `do_thing_a()` or `do_thing_b()`. It feels like there should be a better way to handle this, but the only thing I can think of is to have separate "try" blocks inside each part of the "if" statement:

```
if a:
    try:
        do_thing_a()
    except ValueError as e:
        handle_error()
elif b:
    try:
        do_thing_b()
    except ValueError as e:
        handle_error()
else:
    raise ValueError('thing not recognised!')
```

I don't like the repetition, and I find this more confusing and less readable, but I see no other choice. Is there a nicer solution here? I guess I could define a special exception `UnrecognisedThingError` that I know will not be caught if I wrap my `try-except` statement around the whole `if-else` block, and then re-raise that as a `ValueError` separately (I need a `ValueError` due to some other external code that wants to catch that particular exception type). That's probably better although somehow feels like overkill...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really feels like overloading the ValueError here.
I think you have the right idea with the custom exception.
Such as:

```
class ThingNotRecognizedError(Exception):
    pass

...
try:
    if a:
        do_thing_a()
    elif b:
        do_thing_b()
    else:
        raise ThingNotRecognizedError()

except ValueError as e:
    handle_error()

except ThingNotRecognizedError as e:
    raise ValueError('thing not recognised!')
```

Comment: Yeah this is what I have gone with for now, I cannot think of anything better. It is not so bad to have this extra exception class floating around for just this one purpose I guess.

Comment: IMHO it is the best way to disambiguate raised errors in the code. Hard to say as I'm assuming you scrubbed the code a little, but `ValueError` just feels wrong for the context.

Comment: Yeah this is just a toy example. And yeah it feels like too many ValueErrors for different things flying around, but I am updating some existing code that someone else wrote and don't want to change too much stuff lest I end up having to rewrite the whole package ;).

Answer (score -1):

I don't think what you are trying to achieve is possible, however, what you can do is you can check if the exception raised is from the `else` block with the following:

```
try:
    if a:
        do_thing_a()
    elif b:
        do_thing_b()
    else:
        raise ValueError('thing not recognised!')

except ValueError as e:
    if str(e) == 'thing not recognised!':
        raise ValueError('thing not recognised!')

    handle_error()
```

It works by comparing the exception message and if the exception message is the same as the one you raised manually, it will raise a new exception in the `except` block. However, I would recommend the following:

```
try:
    if a:
        do_thing_a()
    elif b:
        do_thing_b()
    else:
        raise Exception('thing not recognised!')

except ValueError as e:
    handle_error()
```

This way, the `except` block will not catch the exception as it is not a ValueError exception.

Comment: In the first example, you can justr`raise e` in that if instead of creating a new `ValueError` exception. The second one I don't think answers the question because they want a `ValueError` from the calling code.